# Add 1px transparent border to a directory of png files

Tags: image, png

I need to add a 1px transparent border to 1000s of png images in a directory.

Is there a program that would make this painless?

In response to the question:

I have 1000s of icons which are 16x16 and I need to make them 18x18 by adding a transparent border around them.

The problem is how to do it programmatically.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I know a few others who also need 18x18 images and only are able to get 16x16, here's the solution:

Following Blender's comment, install ImageMagick http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Then one very simple dos command:

```
FOR %%c in (C:\16x16\*.png) DO convert %%c -background none -gravity Center -extent 18x18 c:\18x18\%%~nxc
```

This creates a 1px transparent border

Thank you Blender